# gpio command from terminal

Tags: gpio

I have two simple scripts, one in Python, one in bash to turn on and off a LED.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but if a run the bash script nothing happen, while the Python script It works flawless.

The strange thing is that if I run the Python script and after that I run the bash script...it works

after the reboot if I run the bash script first doesn't work

Is there something that I need to add in the /boot/config.txt ?

BASH script

```
   #!/bin/bash
gpio mode 18 out
echo LED on
gpio -g write 18 1
sleep 1
echo LED off
gpio -g write 18 0
```

Python script

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
print ("LED on")
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print ("LED off")
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gpio mode 18 out` will not do anything, because there is no Wiring Pi pin 18

`gpio -g mode 18 out` or `gpio mode 1 out`will work

Comment: I confirm it works now